# is there a way i can group data by "Month" on tabulator js while having a full date?

Tags: javascript, html, json, datetime, tabulator

I'm using tabulator js library. I know there is a group option where i can group through certain fields i have in my data. I have a field date of the format MM/DD/YYYY. I want to group the data in the table by month only not the full date. How can i achieve that? I have tried splitting the string date from my date on '/' and then taking the first part of it as the month. An error on .split('/') appeared plus if it were to work, I did not know how to continue from there. Any ideas of how to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to show us a few rows of the data in your table, and the code you use to invoke tabulator.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need moment.js and then you can do something like:

```
groupBy: function(data){
        return moment(data.dob, "MM/DD/YYYY").startOf("month").format("MMM-YYYY");}
```

Where you specify the input data `format("MM/DD/YYYY")`, then normalize those dates to the start of the month(`startOf("month")` and then return as abbreviated month name with year(`format("MMM-YYYY")`). You could change ```.format("MMM-YYYY") to what suits.

For demo see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aklaver/xa9m0jy8/)